# How will the value, A(2) be available in, line 2, if A(2) is being calculated in, line 3?

Tags: computer-architecture

How will the value, A(2) be available in, line 2, if A(2) is being calculated in, line 3?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that it *doesn't* use the new value, it uses the old value. You want to take the current value of `A[i+1]` and use it to calculate a new value for `A[i]`. If you do each operation in order, you'll always do the operation which uses the old value, before overwriting it with a new value.

The problem is, when you vectorize this, you might end up changing `A[i+1]` at the same time as you're trying to read its old value. But ideally vectorization shouldn't change the result of a process, only how fast it runs. This is why you need the `TEMP` array, to keep the result the same.